# A combination problem about same sum subsets

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, pigeonhole-principle

Suppose $k$ is such that, given any $k$ distinct integers in $\{1,2,\dots,100\}$, there are two distinct subsets with the same sum. What is the minimum possible value of $k$?

I have $8≤ k_{min} ≤10$. For the lower bound, note  $\{1,2,4,8,16,32,64\}$ has size $7$ and no distinct subsets with the same sum. And if you have a subset of size $10$, then there are $1024$ distinct subsets (all lying in $\{0,1,2,\dots,1000\}$, so two distinct subsets must have the same sum.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A276661

Answer (score 1):

The 8-subset $\{54, 76, 87, 93, 96, 98, 99, 100\}$ from an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3570031/finding-a-set-of-maximal-sum-such-that-no-two-subsets-have-the-same-sum) shows that $k \ge 9$.